# Issues parsing UTM-targeted events using GA4

Tags: python, powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, google-analytics-4

So guys, I set up a Python script to extract data from GA4, however, the way GA4 works is different from the old GA, and this is confusing me.
In the past, when using the old GA, I needed to extract such columns:

- date
- event name
- UTM values
- Event count
  Everything that didn't have UTM, he returned me as "(not set)", that is, that it had no value, or else blank. So far so good. From the moment I started using GA4, it only returns values ​​that have some UTM.
  Even directly in Google Analytics itself, when I do the analysis of events, it gives me an X count of that event, such as "page_view". However, when I add a segmentation column, such as the campaign UTM, this value drops, because it only returns the number of events that have values ​​in the UTM, instead of also returning the blank values ​​of the campaign UTM.
  I am not able to think of a second solution to solve this, because I need to return both the blank values ​​in the campaign UTM, as well as the event values ​​that have some UTM, because in the report that I built, there is a filter where I I attribute to which name and traffic source it is, according to the UTM value, and everything that is white I assign as unknown.
  Does anyone know how to help me with this?

I couldn't think of any solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.